# Referencing Specific Function Arguments

Tags: c++, function, arguments

Ok, convoluted question. If I have a function or class constructor (which is really just a special function) that has multiple optional arguments, is there a way to specify one over the other? For example:

`float divide ( float a = 1.0, float b = 1.0 ) { return a / b; }`

How could I specify b *without* specifying a?

P.S. I know this example is a bit contrived, but it gets to the point.

Comment: If the function arguments are of different types that are not convertible to each other, you can use suitable overloading.    Otherwise it is not possible.   Consider:   for your question to make sense, given `result = divide(3.0f)`, how would you  expect a person to work out whether the `3.0f` is the value of `a` or `b`?  Let alone a compiler?

Comment: My current use case has to do with optional input and output file names for a class. Sometimes, I want to have a class read data from a file and just print some end calculation to the screen. Other times, I want it to taken a give set of numbers, and log the calculation to a file. Since both file names are strings, I'm not sure how to handle this neatly

Comment: If you were trying to handle it yourself (as distinct from expecting a compiler to work out your unstated intent) how would YOU make the decision about what action is needed?

Comment: Overload the function.  That's the only way.

Comment: Already. I'll bare this in mind, and see what I can do with it. Thank you

Comment: See [proposal N4172](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) that aimed to bring named arguments to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in option in C++ to name specific arguments in call (like e.g. in Python).

Such named arguments can be faked using helper `struct`s. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Denom {
  float x;
  Denom(float x): x(x) { }
};

struct Num {
  float x;
  Num(float x): x(x) { }
};

float divide(float a, float b) { return a / b; }
inline float divide(const Num &num) { return divide(num.x, 1.0f); }
inline float divide(const Denom &denom) { return divide(1.0f, denom.x); }

int main()
{
  // regular call:
  std::cout << "3 / 2: " << divide(3.0f, 2.0f) << '\n';
  // call with numerator only:
  std::cout << "3 / default: " << divide(Num(3.0f)) << '\n';
  // call with denominator only:
  std::cout << "default / 2: " << divide(Denom(2.0f)) << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 / 2: 1.5
3 / default: 3
default / 2: 0.5
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71f626862596be9e)</kbd>

---

I remembered that the helper `struct` trick can even be extended to allow chaining as well as arbitrary order of arguments. Googling for "C++ named parameters", I found another example in one of the answers to [SO: C++ named arguments implementation with derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46288850/7478597). Example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Args {
  float x, y;
  Args(): x(1.0f), y(1.0f) { }
  Args& num(float x) { this->x = x; return *this; }
  Args& denom(float y) { this->y = y; return *this; }
};

float divide(float a, float b) { return a / b; }
float divide(const Args &args) { return divide(args.x, args.y); }

int main()
{
  // regular call:
  std::cout << "3 / 2: " << divide(3.0f, 2.0f) << '\n';
  // call with numerator only:
  std::cout << "3 / default: " << divide(Args().num(3.0f)) << '\n';
  // call with denominator only:
  std::cout << "default / 2: " << divide(Args().denom(2.0f)) << '\n';
  // args in arbitrary order:
  std::cout << "3 / 2: " << divide(Args().denom(2.0f).num(3.0f)) << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 / 2: 1.5
3 / default: 3
default / 2: 0.5
3 / 2: 1.5
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70e4a777e794a924)</kbd>

---

Once, I saw a simple trick in gtkmm which I use myself from time to time – providing an additional `enum` argument for disambiguation. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum ArgInitNum { InitNum };
enum ArgInitDenom { InitDenom };

float divide(float a, float b) { return a / b; }
inline float divide(ArgInitNum, float a) { return divide(a, 1.0f); }
inline float divide(ArgInitDenom, float b) { return divide(1.0f, b); }

int main()
{
  // regular call:
  std::cout << "3 / 2: " << divide(3.0f, 2.0f) << '\n';
  // call with numerator only:
  std::cout << "3 / default: " << divide(InitNum, 3.0f) << '\n';
  // call with denominator only:
  std::cout << "default / 2: " << divide(InitDenom, 2.0f) << '\n';
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 / 2: 1.5
3 / default: 3
default / 2: 0.5
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c267e5bbfe4fe194)</kbd>

---

Note:

I wouldn't use this technique for plain functions where you can simply use distinct function names. However, it's a pretty option to disambiguate constructors.